# Getting 403 Forbidden laravel broadcasting/auth

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, react-native

Hey guys i been debugging for long but still can't fix the problem.
I get 403 Forbidden laravel broadcasting/auth using pusherjs for private channel. on pusher dashboard logs i can see the event but on browser not firing the event.

> frontend code reactjs

```
const enablePusher = () => {
    var pusher = new Pusher('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
        cluster: 'mt1',
        authEndpoint: Setting.BASE_URL + '/broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            },
        },
    })

    var channel = pusher.subscribe(`private-mc-chat-conversation.${conversation.id}`)
    channel.bind('.Musonza\\Chat\\Eventing\\MessageWasSent', data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
}
```

> BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

> Channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('presence-mc-chat-conversation.{conversationId}', function ($user) {
return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
```

});

Comment: Is there something in your middleware that could stop requests? Can you share middleware code.

Comment: I do not have any middleware for this. but i think its channel.php which creating problem. i update my post with that.

Comment: I think inside the closure of the broadcast you should have an authorization rule like if this user is authorized or not for this channel;  I mean this line return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name]; to be like if the user belongs to this conversation id or not